# Add sorting to MDBTable

Tags: reactjs, mdbtable

I am trying to add sorting to my table. I am trying to avoid reformatting the json with columns: [{}].
Instead, I would like to add the sorting option directly in the MDBTable data.

Is this possible? Or can I specify the columns to the MDBTable?

The below code works fine, but the columns are not sortable.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-center">Coronastatistik för sverige</h1>
      <MDBTable>
        <MDBTableHead>
          <tr>
            <th>Regtion</th>
            <th>Fall</th>
            <th>Fall per 100 000 invånare</th>
            <th>Procent av fall i Sverige</th>
          </tr>
        </MDBTableHead>
        <MDBTableBody>
          {this.state.regions.map(region => (
            <tr>
              <td>{region.Region}</td>
              <td>{region.Fall.toLocaleString()}</td>
              <td>{region.Incidens}</td>
              <td>{region.Procent} %</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </MDBTableBody>
      </MDBTable>
    </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to sort a MDBTable first you have to do it as a MDBDataTable. Then in my case I had to create the json object with the data it needs. For me the messy part was to understand how to build a suitable json object. But after that the table was no problem.

This requires an object in this format

```
data: {
columns: [{
        label: 'Name',
        field: 'name',
        sort: 'asc',
        width: 150 }],
rows: [
      {
        name: 'Tiger Nixon',
        position: 'System Architect',
        office: 'Edinburgh',
        age: '61',
        date: '2011/04/25',
        salary: '$320'
      }}
```

Then you return the MDBDataTable

```
return (
    <MDBDataTable
      striped
      bordered
      small
      data={data}
    />
  );
```